# How to programmatically enter text into a UITextView by Clicking a Button using Swift

Tags: ios, uitextview, uitextfielddelegate

I have a `UITextView` and Two `UIButton`s ( `ButtonOne` and `ButtonTwo`). I would like to type text into this `UITextView` by clicking `ButtonOne` and `ButtonTwo`.

For example, if I click `ButtonOne` it should type “apple” into the `UITextView` and after this if I click `ButtonTwo` it should type “orange” into the `UITextView`. So after I have clicked these two buttons one after another I should have the following text in my UITextView:

> apple orange

I can actually do this currently by using the following line of code:

```
myTextView.text = myTextView.text.stringByAppendingString("orange ")
```

However the problem is that when after type some text into myTextView if I then manually enter some text into myTextView (using the keyboard) and then click `ButtonOne` (or `ButtonTwo`) again, all the manually entered text gets removed from myTextView and I am only left wit the text entered by clicking buttons.

I would like to be able to enter text both by clicking buttons as well as by typing using keyboard interchangeably.

I can do this kind of thing very easily using a RichTextBox control in .NET application. So a related question I have in this connection is what is the equivalent of a .NET RichTextBox control in iOS.

Comment: You don't want to use the stringByAppendingString, instead just assign directly set the text to UITextView .text property. See answer for code.

Comment: he very much does want to append @muazh - OP, show the full code you're using as your description should work

Comment: Can you share your code. Normally what you came up should work

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. By default it should append and UITextView will not clear the current text. How do you create the UITextView is in xib or programmatically?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response to my request for help. The code works, but when I press the ButtonTwo the text typed by the first button gets replaced by the text from the second button. I have tried 'textView.text = textView.text + "Apple " for pushButtonOne and the same for pushButtonTwo and that does give me the desirable result. Please let me know that it would be right approach to use. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with following `code`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourTextView: UITextView!

    @IBAction func appleTap(sender: AnyObject) {
        yourTextView.text = yourTextView.text .stringByAppendingString("Apple ")
    }

    @IBAction func OrangeTap(sender: AnyObject) {
        yourTextView.text = yourTextView.text .stringByAppendingString("Orange ")
    }
```

Above `code` is worked for me if you still having problem then please `write your code` in `question`.

Comment: Many thanks. This worked perfectly. I am very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use .text like the following example. I am a little confused what you are trying to do. Could you please post your code. I hope this helps and you and future viewers.

```
import UIKit
@IBOutlet weak var yourUITextView: UITextView = UITextView!

@IBAction changeTextApple(sender: UIButton) {
    yourUITextView.text = "Apple"
}

@IBAction changeTextOrange(sender: UIButton) {
    yourUITextView.text = "Orange"
}
```